# Streaming Buffer output shows after PHP script finishes execution

Tags: php

I have been experimenting with:

```
ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_start();
$timelimit=10;
while ($timelimit>=0){
    $timelimit=$timelimit-1;
    echo "1";
    sleep(1);
    flush();
    ob_flush();
}

ob_end_flush();
```

php.ini:

```
output_buffering = Off
```

I expect to see "1" added every second until the script completes execution. Instead I see everything only after the script has ended.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What's the point of the experiment? What exactly are you planing to accomplish?

Comment: Learning. But later on I hope to apply it to other things I am working on. I would be happy if it just show another "1" every second.

Comment: @MoonEater916 Why are you using the `ob_*()` functions?

Comment: I just saw it in other examples and copied and when that didn't work i added Flush() to try again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In script PHP output buffer settings ignored by server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320217/in-script-php-output-buffer-settings-ignored-by-server)

Comment: The gzip... it buffers the output too.

Comment: On a side note, if you set ob_implicit_flush, you actually make flush() implicit... So anything that outputs, will call flush right after. Also, turning off output_buffering to simply create one on the start of your script is really weird.

Comment: @Salketer I had to create /var/www/html/.htaccess and added the code in the link you sent. Not sure if .htaccess just works in Apache without some sort of config.

Answer (score 0):

It was working the whole time. I was calling the php via ajax not realizing that the ajax was the cuplrit

```
if ((this.readyState == 4 || this.readyState == 3) && this.status == 200) {
```